# not able to delete my ios app (completely)

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am trying to delete my app from my device. But there's some problem.
Actually am using a AvAudiorecorder, in which, when thje recording code is executed the device asks to allow/disallow the microphone(from ios OS). The problem is am doing some testing for that app. when I choose an option from them, the app doesnt prompt the allow/disallow options again , even after deleting the app from the device.
i.e. when i reinstall, the settings under microphone automatically shows his name. but which is not the case when I run on the VERY first time on device.

I read how to delete app from ios simulator and device, they are not working.

Please Help.

Comment: Is your question about deleting an app or about the alert not showing?

Comment: you can say its regarding both. when i am reinstalling the app, why its already showing it in microphones, under privacy settings

Comment: @borrrden I got my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your device's settings. Go to General - Reset - Reset Location & Privacy

Comment: Hello @chiquis, am new to iOS programming, i mean doing it from last two months, it solved my problem, thanx a lot

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, by the way, this also works to reset any other privacy messages that have already been set. (Access to photographs, location manager, etc). And also, to accept an answer you have to select the check mark next to the answer you one to accept, otherwise your "% of accepted answers index" wont change.

Comment: thank_you, dont know how to add people like you in my circle, over stackoverflow. and why my question is showing -1 , coz somebody marked , as already asked? but i didnt get answer u gave from there

Answer (score 0):

I had the inverse problem; I had an issue in my app where the unnecessary use of AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord was set causing unnecessary microphone usage prompting, settings, etc. My app update got rejected so I fixed the app to set only AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback but I kept seeing the old state in settings->privacy->microphone until I followed this answer.
Interestingly, my app has been again rejected post fixing so I suspect that the app review team have not performed this important reset of the test environment.